# Django app with user authentication at project level

Tags: python, django, authentication

How do I handle user authentication inside an app when the authentication of users is handled at project level?

Im building an app where I need an authenticated user object when creating database entries, but I don't want to deal with the whole signup/sign-in logic inside the app, that should be delt with at a project level instead.

The app requires a user being signed in, but when developing I can't figure out where to put this. Can I "fake" an authenticated user inside the settings.py for the project?

**Update**

I realised that all I had to do, was to log into /admin after adding the @login_required to all my views. Then I'd get the data I needed using request.user and adding models.ForeignKey(User) to the models that needed it

Comment: you want to handel user auth inside app without have to write login code inside this app views?

Comment: I will be adding the @login_required to my views and I will need to get the user model, but while developing the app, it's enough that there is a dummy user

Comment: It enough and if you want to more check on users create custom decorator as needed

Comment: You can make a decorator to check if this admin .... etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no default way to fake a user, but you can easily implement that yourself.

You can simply create a view that logs in a hardcoded user.

```
def force_login(request):
    # this check is not really required, but probably a good idea
    if not settings.DEBUG:
        raise ImproperlyConfigured("Don't use the force_login view in production")
    user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(
        username='user',
        defaults={...})  # set whatever defaults you need
    user.backend = settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS[0]
    login(request, user)
    return HttpResponse('logged in')
```

Now you just have to add this view to your `urls.py`. An alternative approach would be to write this as a middleware.

```
class ForceAuthenticationMiddleware(object):
    """
    Ensures that the request has a logged in user.

    If there is no user, it logs in a default user and return a
    redirect.
    """

    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            return
        user, created = User.objects.get_or_create(
            username='user',
            defaults={...})  # set whatever defaults you need
        user.backend = settings.AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS[0]
        login(request, user)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.get_full_path())
```

Insert that middleware in your `settings.MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES` after     `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',`

Update: I turned this answer into a [blog post](https://consideratecode.com/2016/12/28/how-to-auto-authenticate-a-user-in-django/) and published the middleware on [PyPI](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-always-authenticated).

Comment: Not quite. I will add @login_required to my views, I just don't want to build the part that handles the creating of an account and logging a user in, in order to build the app. My app will be added to an app where users are required be to logged in, that logic is handled by the project and not my app

Comment: @kristiannissen yeah only use login required and specify login url only

Comment: @kristiannissen I rewrote my answer, hopefully understanding your question correctly this time :)

Answer (score 0):

According to Django auth system [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required)

***if you are looking for a way to limit access to logged in users***
use `login_required()` decorator:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def my_view(request):
        #your code
```

By default, the path that the user should be redirected to upon successful authentication is stored in a query string parameter called "next" which is `my_view` in this example finally after user login user object hooked to `request`